# Events: field request

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation

The "Event" object doesn't have an easy way for getting at the object relating to the event.  There's a `link` field, but I don't fancy having to parse the information out of that (although I could).

It'd be nice if the "Event" object had an `object_id` field.  This `object_id` would have a different meaning depending on the `event_type` field:

- `question_posted` => the id of the question
- `answer_posted` => the id of the answer
- `comment_posted` => the id of the comment
- `post_edited` => the id of the post
- `user_created` => the id of the user

This would be much nicer than trying to retrieve the id from the link.

---

Alternatively, if the `event_id` field already fulfills this purpose, then the documentation *really* needs to be updated to reflect that and not simply say:

```
event_id - integer, refers to an event
```

Comment: Unless Kevin has just added it, this field already exists as `event_id`?

Comment: @Jonathan. I thought `event_id` was an identifier for the event itself, and not the thing to which the event refers

Comment: the `event_id` always matches the id in the `link` field. But it is not the most well named field, and the docs do say it "refers to an event", thought there isn't much point having it refer to an event as there's only one method you can get events from. So I'd say the docs are wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan. Thanks; in that light, I've updated my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation was confusing there, `event_id` is the question/answer/etc. id.

I've modified the documentation for the [event type](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/event).